# How do I fix npm missing script

Tags: reactjs, debugging

PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\HTML PROJECTS\React\NewTodo-App> npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-05T09_29_42_788Z-debug.log

I keep getting that error each time I run npm start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your package . json and add this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
```